# Primitive stream vs object stream and actual boxing that occurs

Tags: java, java-stream, primitive, autoboxing

So I understand you can have object streams, i.e. `Stream<T>` and specialist primitive streams, e.g. `IntStream`, `DoubleStream`, etc. One of the benefits of the latter is to avoid autoboxing.

Also if we take `IntStream` as an example, it has specialised operations such as filter that accepts an `IntPredicate`.

I wondered if I had an `IntStream` vs a `Stream<Integer>` at which point you're saving on boxing, e.g.

```
intstream.filter(x -> x >= 50).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

vs

```
stream.filter(x -> x >= 50).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

In the first example, there is no boxing or unboxing that I can see. In the second example where is the boxing / unboxing occurring? Because if stream is a `Stream<Integer>` and the filter accepts a `Predicate<Integer>` then surely there's no need to box/unbox, and the same for `IntConsumer` vs `Consumer<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Stream<Integer>` your stream is already boxed. So depending on how you created it there are several possibilities:

- You have initially boxed values. For example, you had `List<Integer> list` as the input and wrote:

  ```
  stream = list.stream();
  ```
- You boxed your values when creating the stream. For example, you created it like this:

  ```
  stream = Stream.iterate(1, x -> x+1);
  ```

  In this case the first argument is boxed to `Integer.valueOf(1)` and unboxing/boxing also occurs on every lambda (which is `UnaryOperator<Integer>`) invocation. So effectively you have:

  ```
  stream = Stream.iterate(Integer.valueOf(1), x -> Integer.valueOf(x.intValue()+1));
  ```
- You boxed your source explicitly via upstream intermediate operation. For example:

  ```
  stream = IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed();
  ```

  In this case boxing is performed inside the `.boxed()` operation (which is a shortcut for `.mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`).

Comment: what I'm trying to get at here is if I had a source of say a List<Integer> then I've already had to box all its elements. Considering this, I'm wondering whether it would be best to use a Stream<Integer> or IntStream to process it - so I'm looking at the boxing/unboxing that could occur during a the pipeline. For a start getting an IntStream would require unboxing all Integer objects from the list, but then you would possibly have no more boxing/unboxing. But with a Stream<Integer> I cannot see any further boxing only unboxing. Literature commonly refers to frequent boxing though

Comment: @Tranquility, you should not care about *unboxing*: it's absolutely cheap (just single dereference). What's expensive is the *boxing* (an actual object allocation in worst case). Also note that every single numerical operation with `Integer` (addition, comparison, etc.) requires unboxing.

Answer (score 6):

The unboxing happens inside the predicate: in `stream.filter(x -> x >= 50)`, the `Predicate` essentially becomes `(Integer x) -> x.intValue() >= 50`, and `intValue()` is the unboxing step.  Additionally, `System.out.println` does some unboxing itself, in the implementation of `Integer.toString` that ends up being called.

Comment: yes this is what I thought so forgetting about the boxing that may have occured in populating the source of the Stream<Integer> there is not any further boxing but usually unboxing to evaluate the integer elements during lamba expressions? I wondered if when the stream pipeline passes an element to say filter whether it goes in as an int and therefore gets boxed into an Integer - but I doubt this would happen. The point being the benefit of having an IntPredicate argument is not to stop boxing, but to avoid unboxing during the lambda?