# Java mapToInt vs Reduce with map

Tags: java, java-8, mapreduce, reduce

I've been reading up on reduce and have just found out that there is a 3 argument version that can essentially perform a map reduce like this:

```
String[] strarr = {"abc", "defg", "vwxyz"};

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strarr).reduce(0, (l, s) -> l + s.length(), (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2));
```

However I can't see the advantage of this over a mapToInt with a reduce.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(strarr).mapToInt(s -> s.length()).reduce(0, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2));
```

Both produce the correct answer of 12, and both appear to work fine in parallel.

Is one better than the other, and if so, why?

Comment: You're essentially asking what the difference is between `IntStream` and `Stream<Integer>`. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209191/primitive-stream-vs-object-stream-and-actual-boxing-that-occurs. Remember that `IntStream` gives you that "reduction" already implemented: `.sum()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is one better than the other, and if so, why?

With the first `reduce` approach there’s an insidious *boxing* cost.

The `mapToInt.reduce(...)` approach avoids that.

So, the idea is if you're interested in summation, average et al just use the primitive stream specializations as they're more efficient.

By the way, the code:

```
Arrays.stream(strarr).mapToInt(s -> s.length()).reduce(0, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2)
```

can be simplified to:

```
Arrays.stream(strarr).mapToInt(s -> s.length()).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

The three-argument [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is more flexible:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

in comparison with the two-argument [`IntStream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) that accepts and returns only `int` values:

```
int reduce(int identity, IntBinaryOperator op);
```

While `accumulator` in the three-argument version can accept parameters of two different types:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, Integer> acc = (i, str) -> i + str.length();
```

that allows you to omit additional `map` operation:

```
Arrays.stream(strs).reduce(0, (i, str) -> i + str.length(), Integer::sum)
```